# T-SQL Dynamic GROUP BY using @parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I would like to achieve

```
SELECT @param1, @param2, @param3, t.field1, sum(t.amount)
FROM table t
WHERE t.field 2 IS NOT NULL AND
t.field3ID = '12345'
GROUP BY @param1, @param2, @param3
```

What is the best approach? Is building dynamic SQL is the way to go?

Comment: Safe to assume param1, param2, et al hold the names of fields the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic SQL is the only way to go here. However, what kind of table do you have where you have a bunch of optional grouping columns?

Answer (score 1):

I'm boldly assuming that your params hold your field names. Otherwise I see no reason why you would have them there.

**If the grouped items *contains exactly the same values* within the groups**, you could do without grouping by using min or max like this:

```
SELECT Min(@param1), Min(@param2), Min(@param3), t.field1, sum(t.amount)
FROM table t
WHERE t.field 2 IS NOT NULL AND
t.field3ID = '12345'
```

You would still have the problem that **fields can't be selected like that**.

You could use case statements, this works and can be combined with the "Min/Max" philosophy from above if you want to get rid of the group by statements:

```
SELECT 
    case 
        when @param1 = 'colname1' then colname1
        when @param1 = 'colname2' then colname2
        when @param1 = 'colname2' then colname3
        else null
    end, 
    case 
        when @param2 = 'colname1' then colname1
        when @param2 = 'colname2' then colname2
        when @param2 = 'colname2' then colname3
        else null
    end, 
    case 
        when @param3 = 'colname1' then colname1
        when @param3 = 'colname2' then colname2
        when @param3 = 'colname2' then colname3
        else null
    end, 
    t.field1, 
    sum(t.amount)
FROM table t
WHERE t.field2 IS NOT NULL AND
t.field3ID = '12345'
GROUP BY 
    case 
        when @param1 = 'colname1' then colname1
        when @param1 = 'colname2' then colname2
        when @param1 = 'colname2' then colname3
        else null
    end, 
    case 
        when @param2 = 'colname1' then colname1
        when @param2 = 'colname2' then colname2
        when @param2 = 'colname2' then colname3
        else null
    end, 
    case 
        when @param3 = 'colname1' then colname1
        when @param3 = 'colname2' then colname2
        when @param3 = 'colname2' then colname3
        else null
    end,
    t.field1
```

I think you could choose between the following solutions:

- Select all required fields and filter fields at the client side
- Use dynamic SQL
- Create multiple procedures
- Use case statements

It all depends on how you are going to use it.

Comment: I doubt you can group by null, but hopefully that situation will never happen

Comment: Yes, exactly. As I see it, it would be helpful if it breaks when that happens. Otherwise just choose any sensible default column.

Comment: Actually you can group by null. I just tested it. Sorry about that. You can test it here http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/107547/ It is really cool

Answer (score 1):

First of all t.field1 should also be in your group by or handled in the sql with an aggrigate function like min or max

Here is a bit of dynamic sql you can use. It will allow you to use different number of parameters

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (COLUMNNAME varchar(15))
DECLARE @pstring VARCHAR(1000), @sqlstring varchar(5000)

DECLARE @param1 VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @param2 VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @param3 VARCHAR(15)
--declare more columns here

SET @param1 = <colname> -- replace this <colname>
SET @param2 = <colname>
SET @param3 = <colname>
--set the name of the column

INSERT @t SELECT @param1 
UNION ALL SELECT @param2
UNION ALL SELECT @param3
--union all select @param4 etc

SELECT @pstring = COALESCE(@pstring, '') + columnname+',' FROM @t

SET @sqlstring = 'SELECT '+@pstring + 'min(t.field1) field1, sum(t.amount)
FROM table t
WHERE t.field2 IS NOT NULL AND
t.field3ID = ''12345''
GROUP BY ' +stuff(@pstring,len(@pstring), 1,'')

EXEC(@sqlstring)
```

Comment: This should work. It can be optimised slightly: `COALESCE(@pstring, '') + columnname+','` can be changed to `COALESCE(@pstring+',', '') + columnname`, and you thus get the list with no extra commas (no need to use `STUFF()` later). But `min(t.field1)` should then be prepended with a comma, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to group by values you are explicitly passing into your query?

Eliminate the @param1/2/3 from the select statement, eliminate the group by and just do a regular select.  In your code, add your parameters to whatever is expecting the results.  Otherwise you're just creating network traffic.