# SELECT dynamic columns GROUP BY dynamic columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, group-by, dynamic-sql

I need to accomplish the following in the stored procedure:

1. Pass parameterized column names.
2. Select the parameterized column names and provide total group by selected columns.

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sproc (
  @column1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @column2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @startdate DATE,
  @enddate DATE ) AS

BEGIN

  DECLARE @sqlquery NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT @column1, @column2, SUM(amountcolumn)
                                       FROM tablename
                                      WHERE column3 = ''@value3'',
                                            datecolumn BETWEEN ''@startdate'' AND ''@enddate''
                                   GROUP BY @column1, @column2';

  DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(MAX) = '@column1 VARCHAR(MAX),
                                   @column2 VARCHAR(MAX),
                                   @startdate DATE,
                                   @enddate  DATE';

  EXEC sp_sqlexec @sqlquery, @params,
       @column1 = @column1,
       @column2 = @column2,
       @startdate = @startdate,
       @enddate = @enddate;

END

GO
```

Comment: Where does @value3 come from?

Comment: this dynamic sql is built into a sproc that will be used by a ssrs report.  @value3 is a comma seperated multi-select value which is passed as a string parameter to sproc.

Comment: So @value3 is a list of strings, or a list of an integers, or a single string value that happens to be a comma-separated list of values? Can you give an example of this comma-separated string and some examples of the data in column3? I suggest you get an actual query working in Management Studio (your syntax is currently wrong in a couple of ways) before you start trying to build it dynamically.

Comment: Some of the answers to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811092/t-sql-dynamic-group-by-using-parameters) about the same problem contain examples. Have you tried them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `@value3` is a string and is another parameter to the stored procedure, that `datecolumn` is in fact `date`, and ignoring the fact that I have no idea how you can have a schema where the grouping fields can be random like this (which you ignored in other recent questions here):

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT ' 
      + QUOTENAME(@column1) + ', ' 
      + QUOTENAME(@column2) + ', SUM(amountcolumn)
    FROM dbo.tablename
    WHERE column3 = @value3
    AND datecolumn BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
    GROUP BY ' + QUOTENAME(@column1) 
        + ', ' + QUOTENAME(@column2) + ';';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@value3 varchar(255), @startdate date, @enddate date',
    @value3, @startdate, @enddate; 
    -- strongly recommend against sp_sqlexec
    -- it is undocumented and unsupported
```

This also assumes you don't care about order (you probably do and will want to add `ORDER BY` as well as `GROUP BY`).

For more info on dynamic SQL and even further ways to protect yourself from user input:

- [sqlblog.org/dynamic-sql](https://sqlblog.org/dynamic-sql)

Comment: You are answering a question, and 7 years later your answer saves someone's day. That's why I love this site... Thanks :)